# ALSA - unmuting devices?

Tags: android, linux, audio, alsa

I have been trying to capture audio, within a native linux program running on an Android device via adb shell.

Since I seemed to be getting only (very quiet) noise, i.e. no actual signal (interestingly, an Android/Java program doing similar did show there was a signal on that input),
I executed alsa_amixer, which had one entry that looked like the right one:

```
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 31 [49%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 31 [49%] [0.00dB] [off]
```

"off". That would explain the noise.
So I looked for examples of how to use alsa_amixer to unmute the channels, I found different suggestions for parameters like "49% on" or "49% unmute", or just "unmute" none of which works. (if the volume% is left out, it says "Invalid command!", otherwise, the volume is set, but the on/unmute is ignored)

I also searched how to do this programatically (which I'll ultimately need to do, although the manual approach would be helpful for now), but wasn't too lucky there.
The only ALSA lib command I found which sounds like it could do something like that was "snd_mixer_selem_set_capture_switch_all", but the docs don't day what the parameter does (1/0 is not on/off, I tried that ;) )

Comment: This all works on regular Linux. Perhaps Android has a crippled alsa build.

Comment: ...set_capture_switch_all ?
I called that for "Capture" with value = 1.
The program crashed and I got this as console output:

ALSA lib external/alsa-lib/src/conf.c:4487:(parse_args) Unknown parameter 1, 
ALSA lib external/alsa-lib/src/conf.c:4620:(snd_config_expand) Parse arguments error: No such file or directory, 
ALSA lib external/alsa-lib/src/control/control.c:902(snd_ctl_open_noupdate)
Invalid CTL hw:0,0

Comment: [This here program](http://pastebin.com/index/9HZFC9dJ) works for me.

Comment: Ah, thanks! If I set 1, it is [on] now, when using "default" device, "hw:0,0" gives the crash, why?
Still not getting meaningful input apparently, so the search goes on... 
Well since the title is about unmuting devices, it's answered - should I answer myself posting your code, to be able to mark this question "answered" ?

Comment: Btw., I can't use the "default" device for recording - it will only let me set buffer sizes of POT + framesize, e.g. instead 16384, I'll only get 16386, while it's the other way around for the playback channel, but I need both to be the same.
That's a rather weird driver...

Comment: "hw:0,0" is not a sound card, it's a sub-device. "hw:0" is a sound card.

Comment: Ah, of course :-D
Does anyone have an idea why the code linked above may not work for every (sub)device?
I've seen that the audio chip in my device, the WM8962, also has a mixer before the ADC, mixing several input sources, only one of which has a connection - the microphone jack.
Now, the connected pin of the device also appears in alsa_amixer, as "MIXINR IN3R", i.e. a right channel input.
But this is also [off], and the code linked by "n.m." which does switch "Capture" to [on], fails to do so for "MIXINR IN3R".

Comment: Well, this is already beyond my knowledge...

Comment: it looks like android has its claw on this... there's a control device for capture always open

Answer (score 0):

The manual approach to set these things via alsa_amixer does work - but only if android is built with the 'BoardConfigCommon.mk' modified, at the entry: BOARD_USES_ALSA_AUDIO := false, instead of true.

Yeah, this will probably disable ALSA for android, which is why it wouldn't meddle with the mixer settings anymore.

To you android programmers out there, note that this is a very niche use case of course, as was to be expected by my original post to begin with.
This is not what most people would want to do.
I just happen to tinker with an android device here in unusual ways ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the code as question giver suggested, also don't like external links.

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>


int main()
{
    snd_mixer_t *handle;
    snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;

    snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0);
    snd_mixer_attach(handle, "default");
    snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL);
    snd_mixer_load(handle);

    snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
    snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid, 0);
    snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, "Capture");
    snd_mixer_elem_t* elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid);

    snd_mixer_selem_set_capture_switch_all(elem, 0);
    snd_mixer_selem_set_capture_dB_all(elem, 0, 0);

    snd_mixer_close(handle);
}
```